# Adding FLAG_SECURE to achieve Screen Privacy feature, that obscures the screen when app is in background, not working in Android 14

Tags: android, flag-secure

I've been searching the Screen Privacy issues in Android 14 version but couldn't find any open or closed issues related to the version 14. I wonder if anyone knows detailed information why in Android 14 setting the FLAG_SECURE is not working at all to achieve the Screen Privacy and can anybody provide some work-around (if there is) to achieve Screen Privacy like feature?

Comment: It seems to be working fine here, based on a quick test with a banking app. You might consider expanding your question with a [mcve] and a *detailed* explanation of "not working at all".

Comment: Can you share the name of that banking app so that I could personally test it in Android 14

Comment: Quite literally, I asked first. If you expand your question with a [mcve] and a *detailed* explanation of "not working at all", I will name the banking app and will explain why you will not be able to personally test it.